# Euchre Call for partner

Tags: euchre

In Euchre Call for a partner with 6 people playing...if you are playing to 31.  One person has 28, and another has 29.  If they pair up and both go out winning a 4 bid trick, who wins...the person with the most points or the bidder (considering they are different people)?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked but not seen any rules for call your partner games in general where they discuss who wins when multiple people on the same winning hand break the mark for ending the game.

In general when I have been playing we have handled it in the following ways. In a friendly atmosphere it is considered a tie and anyone who hits the mark is considered a winner. In a more competitive atmosphere it is highest score wins. If there is a tie and the bidder is involved in the tie than the bidder wins. If the bidder is not in the tie the win is than considered a tie.

The reasoning for the bidder breaking ties is because they took the action and risk to make the bid. If they are not in the bid it gets a lot harder to determine a tie breaker other than another hand where they are the only ones who can win.

Answer (score -3):

We've played many versions of euchre and we always use the "bidder goes out" rule in this situation.  So your bidder, not the high score is the winner.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).